# How to make EditText stick to top of screen while scrolling the view below it?

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, nestedscrollview

I have worked with CoordinatorLayout and know how to make TabLayout stick to the top of the page when it is beneath the Toolbar.

However, I am working on a new app now, which has the following screen in a fragment. So the toolbar remains fixed at the top, but I want to achieve a scroll effect which moves the EditText from the center of the blue image region to the top of the page (below the Activity's Toolbar).

This is the layout that I am aiming for (taken from Trucaller app) :

1) On launch :

[image: screen 1]

2) On scrolling :

[image: screen 2]

I have tried numerous techniques using CoordinatorLayout and NestedScrollView, but my EditText (SearchBar) always scrolls up along with the entire blue image region (AppBarLayout).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working, thanks to [StickyScrollViewItems](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems) library. Still need to achieve the fade out effect when scrolling up, and fade in when scrolling back down.